# raised button does not shows answer until I select a drop down item even after assigning a default value

Tags: flutter, button, drop-down-menu

I was making a simple S.I Calculator which has a field for principal amount intrest, and time along with that i have a dropdown to select the currency.
Problem is when I press 'calculate' RaisedButton(looking at the image might help) nothing appears on screen (Initially I thought there is problem with buttton but later ) **I found out that after pressing RaisedButton if I selected any item from dropdown then answer appears** why is this happening, I have set an inital value as `_selected = 'Rupee'` am I doing something wrong?.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Simple Intrest Calculator',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        accentColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _currencies = ['Rupee', 'Dollar', 'Pound'];
  final _minPadding = 5.0;
  var _selected = 'Rupee';

  TextEditingController principalCntr = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController roiCntr = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController termCntr = TextEditingController();
  
  String _amount = '0';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    TextStyle styles = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6;
    
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('S.I Calculator'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: _minPadding * 2),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            getImg(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: TextField(
                controller: principalCntr,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: styles,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Principal',
                  hintText: 'Enter principal amount',
                  labelStyle: styles,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: TextField(
                controller: roiCntr,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: styles,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Intrest',
                  hintText: 'Enter intrest rate',
                  labelStyle: styles,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: termCntr,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: styles,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Time',
                        hintText: 'Time in years',
                        labelStyle: styles,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 50,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      value: _selected,
                      onChanged: (newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selected = newVal;
                        });
                      },
                      items: _currencies.map((selectedVal) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: selectedVal,
                          child: Text(selectedVal),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Text('Calculate'),
                      onPressed: (){
                        _amount = _calculateReturns();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      child: Text('Clear', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),),
                      onPressed: (){
                        debugPrint('pressed');
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(_amount, style: styles,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String _calculateReturns(){
    double principal = double.parse(principalCntr.text);
    double roi = double.parse(roiCntr.text);
    double year = double.parse(termCntr.text);

    double sI = principal + (principal*roi*year)/100;
    String res = 'After $year years, you get $sI';
    return res;
  }

  Widget getImg() {
    AssetImage img = AssetImage('images/money.jpg');
    Image image = Image(image: img, width: 125, height: 125);
    return Container(
      child: image,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(_minPadding * 10),
    );
  }
}
```

This is after i click Raised Button
[image]

This is after i select an item from dropdown but do not click on the button again:
[image]

Code walkthrough:

1. made a list of _currencies.
2. added textinput fields dropdown button and two raised buttons.
3. when calculate button is pressed `_calculateReturns()` is called which returns a value and stores it in `_amount`
4. Output is just a Text widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to update the screen when pressing on the button, remember every time you need to change the content of the page or update it you have to call the method :

```
       setState(() {   
       
       // code here for values to be updated
       });
```

so in your onPressed function of Raised button you have to add it like that :

```
 onPressed: (){
    _amount = _calculateReturns();
    setState(() {    });
               }
```

Comment: Yes!! it was working that way because setState was only defined in dropdown menu thats why result appeared after selecting it.

Comment: exactly that's the reason why it was working only for drop down menu.